# Complex Loop Optimization

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that takes a state and an action, and returns a new state that results from applying the received action in the original state.

My problem is I did code a complex `loop` that I would like to optimize it so that it will bring me a more clear function to read and more optimized.

I have this complex *"pseudocode"* `loop` part of that function source:

```
(loop for l from 0 upto (1- (array-dimension variable1 0)) do
  (if (not (aref variable1 l 0))
    (1+ max-height)
    (return)))
```

What chance do I have to make this `loop` more simple and optimized?

The [Loop Documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm) and the [DoTimes Documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm) don't seems to me enough clear to make the changes on my code and I say sorry for that. Any explanation will be valuable to me.

Comment: I bet that snippet doesn't work whatsoever.  What exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: The loop is suppose to make a line from a *Tetris Game* to be decremented and that way the object will comedown in case it has `NIL` elements in column one.

Comment: **decf** is supposed to modify a place.  I'm not sure whether array-dimension is a place you should try to modify.  The function **1-** may be what you're looking for there.

Comment: The code snippet has multiple errors. It makes no sense.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are right the code was a unclean and wrong example. I did my changes, thank you.

Comment: You are also right @RainerJoswig this is updated now, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code probably had some errors, since there were syntax problems, array-dimension wasn't being called with the right number of arguments, etc., but your loop can easily be turned into a dotimes.  It would be something like this (but note that you'll need to check whether you want to refer to array or object):

```
(dotimes (i (array-dimension array 0))  ; array here
  (unless (aref object i 0)             ; but object here?
    (decf max-height)))
```

Based on the updates to the question, I think we can refine this a bit.  From the code, we can tell that you expect to have a two dimension array of (generalized) booleans, and you're trying to count the true elements in the first column. Here's what such a board might look like:

```
(defparameter *board* #2A((nil t nil)
                          (t t t)
                          (t t t)))
```

Notice that there is *one* true value in its first row, and *two* true values in the first column.  Now, you could write a **dotimes** loop to count the number of true values in the first column with something like this:

```
(let ((max-height 0))
  (dotimes (i (array-dimension *board* 0) max-height)
    (when (aref *board* i 0)
      (incf max-height))))
;=> 2
```

However, I think that **loop** is actually cleaner here, if you take advantage of some of its features.  You can use **below** instead of **upto**, and **from** defaults to **0**, so you can omit it.  You can use **count** to count true values, and then the value of the count is returned by default:

```
(loop for i below (array-dimension *board* 0)
   count (aref *board* i 0))
;=> 2
```

Comment: I have update my example @JoshuaTaylor as you can see, to be more clear and with the right code. If you want, you can change yours in that way. Thank you.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto See my edit.  I think you can actually be more concise with loop than with dotimes, but I've provided updates solutions for both.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @JoshuaTaylor. However, the "array-dimension wasn't being called with the right number of arguments" you say are already on the right form.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto I'm not sure what your last comment means.  The code in the update that I posted runs and produces the output that I've shown.  **array-dimension** needs two arguments:  the array and the axis whose dimension you want.

Comment: Yes and my `array-dimension` has 2 arguments.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Yes, it does now, but the part of the answer where I said that it was called with the wrong number of arguments was based on the *original* code that you posted, which included `(array-dimension 0)`, which had the wrong number of arguments.    In general, it's not a great idea to change the code in questions, since (as we've seen) it can invalidate answers that address issues in the original version, and makes comment discussions confusing.  It also makes the question harder to answer, since it becomes sort of a moving target.